# oozie job configuration: without XML?

Tags: xml, oozie

What are the alternatives for configuring Ooozie workflows without using XML (i.e. json, for example would be nice).  Also I am curious if there are bindings for writing oozie configurations in python/ruby or other script based languages.

Answer (score 4):

Take a look at [gradle-oozie-plugin](https://github.com/MansurAshraf/gradle-oozie-plugin):

> gradle-oozie-plugin provides a simple Groovy DSL for Apache oozie workflow because creating flows in XML causes serious brian damage!

Example workflow:

```
oozie {
first_map_reduce = [
            name: "first_map_reduce",
            type: "mapreduce",
            delete: ["${jobTracker}/pattern"],
            jobXML: "job.xml",
            ok: "end",
            error: "fail",
            configuration: [
                    "mapred.map.output.compress": "false",
                    "mapred.job.queue.name": "queuename"
            ]
    ]
}
```

Comment: It appears like this requires compilation, right?  would be nice if this couldbe read at runtime.

Comment: Don't aware of solution that allows to do it at runtime. Oozie reads workflow definitions from HDFS and they should be in XML (or Oozie itself should be modified to understand some other format).

Comment: Probably it is possible to write some proxy over HDFS that will convert DSL to XML on-the-fly and point Oozie at this proxy instead of real HDFS. But such solution doesn't seem to be very elegant :)